# Different Codebase in the same Android application

Tags: android, kotlin

In android, I am making a one app. When the person first opens, he can choose whether to select "I am a student" or "I am a teacher". Based on this selection, the entire app will run and have different functionality, different Firebase project connection, etc.

I thought I would create Phone/Tablet modules - *":student"* and *":teacher"* and call them from the *":app"* module but for that, I need 3 apps to be installed, which is pointless.

What I should do so that I keep both student's and teacher's code independent from each other and view them inside the same application?

Answer (score 1):

[On Demand Modules](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/on-demand-dynamic-delivery#0)
You build separate modules for student and teacher, i linked codelabs exercise you can check it to see how it ia done.